# Which entries could you change to make this 2 by 2 matrix diagonalizable ? [Strang P309 6.2.14]

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

> For all $c \in \mathbb{C}$, the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}
>     c & 1 \\
>     0 & c \\
>     \end{bmatrix}$
>
> is not diagonalizable because the rank of $A - cI = 1.$
>   Change one entry to make $A$ diagonalizable. Which entries could you change?

**Official Solution:** Changing any entry except $A(1,2) = 1$ makes $A$
diagonalizable ($A$ will have two different eigenvalues).

**Solution from P4 on http://www.math.montana.edu/~geyer/2010/fall/221.html:**

${\Large{\color{red}{[}}} \;$ Changing the 1 to a 0 obviously diagonalizes the matrix, and thus diagonalizable.   $\; {\Large{{\color{red}{]}}}}$
Changing any of the $c$'s to a different number diagonalizes the matrix because it will have 2 different eigenvalues.
Changing the 0 to something else will also lead to two different eigenvalues and diagonalize the matrix.

$\Large{{1.}}$ The first solution states that $A(1, 2) = 1$ shouldn't be changed, while the second solution says that it can be (as I signalised with the red brackets). Which is right and which is wrong?

$\Large{{2.}}$ Are there more efficient solutions, superior to inspecting each entry of the matrix?

Comment: I do not understand your "The two solutions discord with A(1,2)=1. Which is right and which is wrong?" what actually are asking for?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Thanks. I just rewrote it. Better?

Comment: Yes it is better now... the point is they are excepting diganonalizable matrices (which are not already diagonal)... so the point of making $1$ to $0$ does not seem to be interesting...

Comment: I would interpret the exercise as follows: Change one entry by an amount with absolute value $<\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ can be any positive constant (arbitrarily small). Which entry can you pick so that you are **guaranteed** to get a diagonalizable matrix?

Answer (score 2):

- If you change one of the entries $A(1,1)$ or $A(2,2)$ the matrix $A$ becomes with **two distinct eigenvalues** so it's **diagonalizable**.
- If you change the entry $A(2,1)$ then we verify easily that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ has two **distinct complex eigenvalues** so it's also **diagonalizable**.
- Finaly if we change the entry $A(1,2)$ the matrix $A$ stil has the **only eigenvalue** $c$ but since it isn't a **scalar matrix** *(except if $A(1,2)=0$)* hence **it isn't diagonalizable**.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As regards your last bullet, the **solution from P4** says "Changing the 1 to a 0 obviously makes the matrix diagonal, and thus diagonalizable." Thus are they wrong?